# OpenGL on Windows uses Tons of CPU when SwapBuffers is called on a RenderThread

Tags: multithreading, opengl, cpu, swap, buffer

Ok, so I have been running into some threading issues with OpenGL on Windows. I'm using C# .NET to wrap GL. I'm on Windows7 x64.

So ive tried two different tests. In each test i'm rendering a untextured quad(aka two triangles). The CPU hit seems to be related to SwapBuffers from what I can tell.

Single threaded test(This works fine)::

```
{
Draw stuff;
SwapBuffers;
Sleep(15);
}
```

RenderingThread test(This eats all my CPU)::

```
{
Draw stuff;
SwapBuffers;
//glFinish(); //<< If used this seems to make the CPU usage normal
Sleep(15);
}
```

I know this example is simplistic, but the real question is why does OpenGL suck all my CPU when calling SwapBuffers on a different thread other then the one the Windows GUI thread runs on?? And why does glFinish() seem to fix this? Everybody say's not to use glFinish, so i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong or if OpenGL just sucks on Windows...?

I run the same test on OSX, CPU seems normal. I run the same test with D3D9 & D3D10 on windows, CPU seems normal. Haven't tested on Linux as my L-box is down.

Comment: What are you rendering? (How complex is it) Is VSync on or off? What framerate do you get?

Comment: The question now is: Does it really consume the CPU time, or does it just fall for a (well known) miscalculation. Try replacing that (commented out) glFinish with a Sleep(1); if that reduces your CPU consumption as well, its just a miscalculation, because now instead of the idle process your rendering thread recieves all the spare CPU time. Also try starting a few computational heavy programs and see how the compete with your program.

Comment: All cases are 60fps. Hmm, I'm not using wglSwapInterval, could that be a problem on windows? Ill try & see what that does.

Comment: Actually, most of the actual rendering is only performed by the graphics driver when it receives a swap message. Until then, it mainly gathers render calls and their parameters. So if a lot of CPU time is consumed when swapping your render buffers, this might indeed be a hint that the driver uses a software emulation for some of the render tasks. It would be interesting to know what hardware you are running your test on, whether the drivers are up to date, and what render operations your program is performing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is simply solved by doing:

```
glFlush();
glFinish();
```

Before calling::

```
wglSwapBuffers(dc); // Windows
glxSwapBuffers(dc, handle); // Linux
cglFlushDrawable(ctx); // OS X
```

Although drivers make a big difference with OpenGL on Windows, and Windows still performs far better with Direct3D.

Comment: It's extremely driver-dependent on any system, *particularly* with OpenGL involved, as hardware and often driver support for that API can be lousy, emulated or flat-out translated to D3D instructions for the hardware.

Comment: As ive seen this seems to be very true.  Thats why using D3D on windows is a must if you care about performance.

Comment: @LovelyHanibal IDK what you're making but I recommend you only use GL on the main-thread of your app. Just dispatch GL calls on there if you have too. The GL context just breaks down on some platforms if you don't.